# How can I build a new channel in Craft CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, craftcms

I have 2 channels existing in Craft.
Blog and Recipes.
I need to build another channel to hold a list of books that the client can add to in the CMS.
So essentially I need to build a copy of one of these Channels so I'm guessing I can reuse a lot of the code.
Can someone please sent me in the right direction on how to achieve this?
I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

In the CMS you can create a new channel via Settings > Section > New Section, and then assign any fields the entries in that section will need. To display that content you'll need to create a template to retrieve whatever data the entries in that channel will hold. You may be able to re-use the existing code from another channel, it's impossible to say without seeing your templates.

[Craft Docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/) are the best place to start if you want to learn about templating.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a books channel using the same entry type from the blog/Recipes channel. Just add a different name, handle, entry URI format (slug), and template to make it different. Now copy the same templates (twig) files of that blog/recipes channel and paste by changing the name. Now you need to open that files and just need to change the handle of that channel everywhere in the code.

So this will create your new channel Books same like blog/recipes channel with the same fields. If you want to change any fields then you can't copy the channel like explained.

Thanks.